# Q: A basis for a topology on $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R};[0,1])$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology on $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R};[0,1])$:

$$\mathcal{B}=\{\;V_{f,k,\epsilon}\;|\;k\in\mathbb{N},\; \epsilon>0,\; f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R};[0,1])\;\}$$

where
$$V_{f,k,\epsilon}=\{\;g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R};[0,1])\;|\;\max_{0\le i\le k} |g^{(i)}(x)-f^{(i)}(x)|<\epsilon,\;\forall x \in [0,1]   \;\} $$

Since at this stage I'm not familiar yet with advanced theorems or other tools, my try for a solution is by definition (see [Munkres p.78](http://math.ucsb.edu/~bigelow/145/munkres.pdf)).

That $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies condition (1) can be simply shown when we take $h\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R};[0,1])$ and consider $V_{h,k,\epsilon}$ (for all $k\in\mathbb{N},\; \epsilon>0$). However, I've struggled to show that $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies (2), but to little avail. What I've got thus far is this:

Let $h \in V_1\cap V_2$, where $V_1=V_{f_1,k_1,\epsilon_1},\; V_2=V_{f_2,k_2,\epsilon_2} \in \mathcal{B}$ (assuming that $V_1\cap V_2 \neq \emptyset$). Assume WLOG that $k_1 \leq k_2$.

Next, I tried to to make use of an $f_3\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R};[0,1])$ to construct a $V_3 \subseteq V_1\cap V_2$ that satisfies condition (2) of the definition. By intuition, I was thinking that $f_3=\frac{f_1+f_2}{2}$ will be a good choice, but I couldn't figure out how to construct $V_3=V_{f_3,k_3,\epsilon_3}$ properly. In particular, my analysis have got me thinking that taking $k_3=k_1$ will be suitable. However, I couldn't find a suitable $\epsilon_3$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of $f_3=(f_1+f_2)/2$, you need to choose $f_3\in V_1\cap V_2$ by non-emptiness of $V_1\cap V_2$, and you can proceed then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have $V_1 = V_{f_1, k_1, \varepsilon_1}, V_2 = V_{f_2, k_2, \varepsilon_2}$, and we need to show that for *any* $f_3 \in V_1 \cap V_2$ (we cannot choose $f_3$, it can be any point in the intersection) some $V_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ exists with $f_3 \in V_3 \subseteq V_1 \cap V_2$.

To get $f_3 \in V_3$ it's easiest to choose $V_3 = V_{f_3, k_3, \varepsilon_3}$ for some values $k_3 \in \mathbb{N}, \varepsilon_3>0$, yet to be determined.

Also choose $k_3 = \max(k_1,k_2)$, as we need to "control" at least the distance of derivatives up to the $k_3$'th one the $V_1,V_2$ has a condition on derivatives that go that high. (You chose the minimum instead.)

Denote by $||f - g|| = \max \{|f(x) - g(x)|, x \in [0,1]\}$ (this is by itself already a distance function!), and we know that $$||f_1 - f_3|| < \varepsilon_1, ||f^{(1)}_1 - f^{(1)}_3|| < \varepsilon_1, \ldots ,||f^{(k_1)}_1 - f^{(k_1)}_3|| < \varepsilon_1$$
and also that
$$||f_2 - f_3|| < \varepsilon_2, ||f^{(1)}_2 - f^{(1)}_3|| < \varepsilon_2, \ldots ,||f^{(k_2)}_2 - f^{(k_2)}_3|| < \varepsilon_2\text{.}$$

Fix $0 \le k \le k_3$. Then we have "wiggle room" $w_k = \min(\varepsilon_1 - ||f^{(k)}_1 - f^{(k)}_3||, \varepsilon_2 - ||f^{(k)}_2 - f^{(k)}_3||) > 0$, where the $\min$ reduces to just one term if it happened that $k_3 \ge k > \min(k_1,k_2)$, so that we have no guarantees on the other difference. So we take all the strictly positive differences guaranteed by the conditions above, grouped by "derivative level" $k$.

Now define $\varepsilon_3 = \min\{w_k: k = 0,\ldots,k_3\} > 0$. Then using the triangle inequality for $||.||$ (which follows easily from the one for $|.|$ in the reals, so it's quite elementary) one shows (do this!) that for every $g$ and every $0 \le k \le k_3$ we have that from $||g^{(k)} - f^{(k)}_3|| < \varepsilon_3$ we can conclude that $||g^{(k)} - f^{(k)}_i|| < \varepsilon_i$ for $i = 1,2$ and from this it follows that $V_{f_3, k_3, \varepsilon_3} \subseteq V_1 \cap V_2$ as required.